# Datepicker in Ajax Modal Pop Up

Tags: ajax, datepicker

I am using Modal Popup on click to call a FORM from Ajax, my issue is that the datepicker is not working in modal pop up + Ajax FORM

here is code

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myId" class="pickUpClass">Add</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">      
   <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="post" id="Form2">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="panel-body panel-body-nopadding cancelForm" style="max-height:400px; overflow:auto;">       

        </div>            
  </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**AJAX CODE for calling FORM**

```
$('a.pickUpClass').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AJAX.php", // 
        success: function(msg){
            $(".Form2").html(msg);
        },
        error: function(){
            //alert("failure");
        }
    });

});
```

**AJAX.PHP**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="pickUpDate" id="pickUpDate" required>
```

when i call AJAX.php directly, the datepicker works perfectly and calling through ajax function datepicker is not working..

What can i do..??

Comment: Why do you send a `POST` ajax request? I don't see that you're sending any data with it.

Comment: srry, i forgot to mention i m sending a data-id with the ajax.. on that id my form is changing

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` datepicker?

Comment: Bootstrap & jQuery datepicker..

Answer (score 2):

If you want add a new `bootstrap-datepicker`, you must initialize the input which should be the datepicker by calling `.datepicker()` on it.

Change your ajax callback function to:

```
success: function(msg){
    $(".Form2").html(msg);

    $('#pickUpDate').datepicker({
        //options object
    });
}, ...
```

Comment: Super helpful! Thanks! I spent some time trying to figure out the recipe for having the datepicker within a jQuery UI dialog (modal)... using Drupal 7.x.